# Python defaultdict behaviour

Tags: python, defaultdict

I ran into some behaviour that suprised me a little today.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: "test")
```

Now `d[0]`returns `"test"` as expected, but `d.get(0)` actually returns None. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Read through [the `defaultdict` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It explains why `.get()` returns `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. Aside from `mydict[x]`, *all other methods work exactly the same as a regular `dict`*. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

> Return a new dictionary-like object. defaultdict is a subclass of the
> built-in dict class. It overrides one method and adds one writable
> instance variable. The remaining functionality is the same as for the
> dict class and is not documented here.

The method it overrides is `__missing__`, and as further elaborated:

> This method is called by the `__getitem__()` method of the dict class
> when the requested key is not found; whatever it returns or raises is
> then returned or raised by `__getitem__()`.
>
> Note that `__missing__()` is not called for any operations besides
> `__getitem__()`. This means that **`get()` will, like normal dictionaries, return `None` as a default rather than using default_factory.**

Emphasis added.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the expected, [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) behaviour (emphasis in original):

> Note that `__missing__()` is *not* called for any operations besides `__getitem__()`. This means that `get()` will, like normal dictionaries, return `None` as a default rather than using `default_factory`.